# How to avoid holding too much logs in `Writer Monad`?

Tags: scala, monads, writer

When learning the [`Writer Monad`](http://adit.io/posts/2013-06-10-three-useful-monads.html), I found it will collect the `log` value of each step, and then combine them together.

I have a question about the performance: When can I log them? If a method runs thousands of times, and it will hold many many strings in memory for a long time. I can only log them to file after it returns.

How do we use `Writer Monad` to log logs in real world? Is there any way to log the logs just in time?

Comment: You can actually log messages to outer world and keep only the list of critical errors. There is a nice example of wrapping database transaction using RWS monad: http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/07/27/readerwriterstate.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no. Writer is intended to make logging pure and introspectable; flushing parts of it would violate that.

In practice you could probably make a `Monoid` that violates the laws by e.g. writing out the list whenever it gets too long. But that would sacrifice most of the benefits of using Writer in the first place.

I'd recommend benchmarking your requirements and explicitly `run`ing and logging out the `Writer` at a granular, reasonable level e.g. per web request or per logical transaction.